# QGIS - Graphical modeler - output shapefile is not altered

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, qgis-modeler, algorithm, service-area

## Graphical Modeller

I started using Graphical Modeler in QGIS (learned about it few weeks back and I was really excited about this). Unfortunately (probably due to lack of skill) I cannot seem to make it work. You can see my algorithm in a figure below (Fig. 1). The results from this algorithm returns the original grid file with no difference whatsoever. I would expect a grid shapefile with the same geometry as the original one, but with additional attribute that is the result of join attributes by location summary to return a count of intersecting polygons from the Convex Hull (from the Service Area from the points) on individual parts of the grid. The model is valid and can be run.

[image]
***Figure 1: Algorithm schematics.***

### Algorithm code

You can see the code for the algorithm below:

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : DOSTUPNOST ÚZEMÍ
Group : 
With QGIS : 32003
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
import processing


class DostupnostZem(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('INFRASTRUCTURE', 'INFRASTRUCTURE', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('POINTS', 'POINTS', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('GRID', 'GRID', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('GridWalkingDistance001', 'GRID - WALKING DISTANCE - 001', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(5, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # SA - DOCH_VZD
        alg_params = {
            'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,  # Both directions
            'DEFAULT_SPEED': 50,
            'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
            'INCLUDE_BOUNDS': False,
            'INPUT': parameters['INFRASTRUCTURE'],
            'SPEED_FIELD': '',
            'START_POINTS': parameters['POINTS'],
            'STRATEGY': 0,  # Shortest
            'TOLERANCE': 0,
            'TRAVEL_COST2': QgsExpression(' @DOCH_VZD ').evaluate(),
            'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',
            'VALUE_BOTH': '',
            'VALUE_FORWARD': '',
            'OUTPUT_LINES': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['SaDoch_vzd'] = processing.run('native:serviceareafromlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Create spatial index SA
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['SaDoch_vzd']['OUTPUT_LINES']
        }
        outputs['CreateSpatialIndexSa'] = processing.run('native:createspatialindex', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Convex hull
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['SaDoch_vzd']['OUTPUT_LINES'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ConvexHull'] = processing.run('native:convexhull', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Join attributes by location (summary)
        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
            'INPUT': parameters['GRID'],
            'JOIN': outputs['ConvexHull']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_FIELDS': ['\'01\''],
            'PREDICATE': [0],  # intersects
            'SUMMARIES': [0],  # count
            'OUTPUT': parameters['GridWalkingDistance001']
        }
        outputs['JoinAttributesByLocationSummary'] = processing.run('qgis:joinbylocationsummary', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['GridWalkingDistance001'] = outputs['JoinAttributesByLocationSummary']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Create spatial index CH
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['ConvexHull']['OUTPUT']
        }
        outputs['CreateSpatialIndexCh'] = processing.run('native:createspatialindex', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'DOSTUPNOST ÚZEMÍ'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'DOSTUPNOST ÚZEMÍ'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return DostupnostZem()
```

### To clarify

1. I am using inputs that have been created before separately and are in the same coordinates (Czech standard Křovák).
2. I added the creation of spatial indexes to make the calculation faster (yet I still get a warning that for the last step, no spatial index exists).
3. I used Buffer instead of Convex Hull before, but that proved to be too long to calculate, but in the future I would like to use buffer. This should not matter at all.
4. This algorithm uses place of residence of people to calculate a reachability of individual places in a certain walking distance. The grid is there to visualise this better.
5. Both the Service area distance and buffer distance (not in the latest iteration) are variables to more easily change it in the future.
6. While this is not a long algorithm, I would like to be able to reproduce it in the future with little to no knowledge about some more advanced functions in QGIS my other team members and therefore I would like this to work, even though, this can easily by done step by step.

## QUESTION

**After running my algorithm, the output file (grid joined with additional data) is not altered in any way - just like the original grid (no data joined). What is the problem?**

Comment: Can you share the model?

Comment: Yes, I can, you can find it on this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fCx-Bx4rmzjQzH160tbF7TAszB0fC3-d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's a bit complicated to understand what exactly the model should do. Can you add a screenshot showing your geometries - and can you share sample data for testing? Otherwise, people have to guess what kind of data you use and probably it won't fit your needs.

Comment: You have `0 dependencies selected` - if you `Select all`, does this help?

Comment: I didn't know the dependencies are necessary in such a simple model. When I get a chance later, I will try to run it with dependencies selected. Unfortunately, I cannot share the data as they are classified. What this model should do - based on point layer and network line layer it should create a service area (lines), then from those either by Buffer or Convex Hull it should create polygons that show accessibility from the points. Then I need to calculate number of overlapping polygons created like this over a grid polygon layer. I will try the dependencies or try to provide some other data.

Comment: Not sure if dependencies are the problem. It would still be great if you could provide fake data for testing - data that does not disclose any information, but that has the same structure as the one you need. By the way: what you describe sounds like Iso Area. Did you have a look at Iso Area creation with QNEAT3 plugin? https://root676.github.io/IsoAreaAlgs.html

Comment: Yes I plan to prepare fake data to send, first Ill check the dependencies and the Iso Area. Thanks for the tip. Even if Iso Area will be what I am looking for, I still want to find out why my model is not working as I plan to use it more in the future.

Comment: ISO Area is not what I am looking for, it is important to have the calculation of how many features intersect on the grid polygons. I have tried to select dependencies and now I am getting this error "Feature could not be written to Convex_hulls_a597a610_2c80_48f2_9451_738589db54a3: Could not add feature with geometry type LineString to layer of type Polygon". Cannot fix it. Seems to be problem between service area and convexhull. Sending fake population data (much faster to test - less points). https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wTzdcSr0dWllt0Sq5p3N1tyXM_KDTQ6A/view?usp=sharing (OSM infrastr.)

Comment: I have found one mistake, I had attribute in simple quotes instead of just the name. But this did not fix the error. I am getting an alert that in convex hull geometry linestring could not be written into polygon and I dont understand why.